# Does Qt Creator offer a "quick fix" shortcut or command to include a file for a class?

Tags: qt, include, qt-creator

Most IDEs have a "quick fix" option that offer to import/include a class or function when its is not yet declared. Does Qt Creator offer that?

Right now I have

```
class TableModel : QAbstractTableModel {

};
```

but because I have not yet included the include file for `QAbstractTableModel`, it gives me an error: `"expected class name"`.

Is there a shortcut or command so that the IDE includes the correct file for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I cannot find it in the menus, but in my macOS system it has shortcut `Option + Enter`.

This can be changed in `Preferences -> Text Editor -> Environment`, and then filtering for "`QuickFix`".